# Spring Transactional Unit Tests - Hibernate Queries Not Rolling Back

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, junit

I am using Spring 3, and Hibernate 3.5, I am not getting my transactions to rollback in the test environment, which has me worried they would not be rolled back in production either.

Test Class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = MyConfigurationLoader.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class DashTemplateRepositoryTest extends AbstractMulitpleDataSourceSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    DashTemplateRepository dashTemplateRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveCategory() {
        int initialCount = getCategoryCount();

        Category c = new Category();
        c.setName("mynewcategory");
        dashTemplateRepository.save(c);

        assertEquals(initialCount + 1, getCategoryCount());
    }
}
```

Which extends a custom class :

```
public abstract class AbstractTransactionalTemplateTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    protected SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    DashTemplateRepository dashTemplateRepository;

    @Resource(name = "dashDataSource")
    public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    } ..snip...
```

UPDATE: I needed to do the simpleJdbcTemplate insertion because I have multiple dataSources, and by default this test class can't handle that, I wasn't able to find a spring supported solution, but on the spring forums a contributor posted this workaround.  The rollback problem existed before I extracted this super class.  I'm assuming the problem is more basic than that, hibernate doesn't seem to be aware of the transaction manager, is there any way I can prove that?

Datasource Bean:

```
<bean id="dashDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashtemplate"/>
        <property name="username" .../>
        <property name="password" .../>
    </bean>
```

My Context-text.xml (simplified, left out some of it)

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dashDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dash.Category</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dashTemplateRepository" class="com.wdp.DashTemplateRepositoryHibernateTemplateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

The test runs fine, my object is persisted, but it is never rolled back, there doesn't appear to be any errors either

Comment: What does `DashTemplateRepositoryHibernateTemplateImpl` look like?

Comment: why should it be rolled-back?

Comment: @Bozho: I believe the `defaultRollback` attribute of `@TransactionConfiguration` is supposed to indicate that

Comment: so a rollback should happen even for a successful transaction? Sounds strange :) Furthermore, `true` seems to be the default value.

Comment: @bozho that's the default behavior of the spring transactional test suite. that way you can run integration tests on real databases without polluting them

Comment: `AbstractMulitpleDataSourceSpringContextTests` seems to be a custom class, at least I can't find it. What does it extend?

Comment: @seanizer - yes, it's a custom class, I put in the relevant portion of that class, it extends springs tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that MySQL was using MyISAM instead of InnoDB - rollbacks are not supported by MyISAM

Answer (score 2):

This is what my base test class looks like and works fine for me.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class BaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
//....
}
```

Comment: this worked for me many months later in a different project - didn't solve the original issue though